# React Native: Unabe to resolve module ./src/Home from.... / None of these files exist:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a ReactNative Project. I am a beginner so this question might seem silly. I am creating a basic navigation for a login screen and keep getting this error message

'Unable to resolve module ./src/Home from /app7-react-native/App.js:

Then it says none of these files exist

Here is my App. js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from '.src/Home';
import Login from './src/Login';



const Navigator = createStackNavigator ({

    Home: { screen: Home},
    Login: { screen: Login},

});

const App = createAppContainer(Navigator);

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';


export default class Home extends React.Component {
    static navigationsOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: navigation.getParam('name'),

        };
    };

    render() {
        const { navigate, state } = this.props.navigation; 

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text>Hello {state.params.name}</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to home screen"
                    onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, 
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'; 

import { Text, View, TextInput, Stylesheet, Button, Touchableopacity  } from 'react-native';


export default class Login extends React.Component {
    static navigationsOptions = {
        title = 'Login',

    };
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button 
                    title="Go to profile screen"
                    onPress={() => navigate(
                        'Profile', { name: 'Jane'}
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this `'.src/Home'` with `'./src/Home'`;

**and your folder structure must be :**

```js
App. js
src
   Home.js
   Login.js
```

Comment: Try here https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/navigation-example
and check package.json you may miss some dependencies, and I suggest you to use last version from react navigation  here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

2 fixes need to be done here

1. Replace '.src/Home' with './src/Home' in your `App.js` file.

> MyRNProject

> ```
> App.js
> src
>    Home.js
>    Login.js
> ```

2. You seem to be calling **"Home"** from inside of `Home.js` onPress function. You are creating an infinite loop here. Change it to a different screen like **Login** or **Profile**
   [image]